# Django update on shared hosting - Permission denied

Tags: django, hosting, shared, fastcgi

I have version 1.3.1 Django installed on my shared hosting plan. It works fine. The problem is i need to update it to 1.4 but i'm getting an error

```
error: could not delete '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/__init__.py': Permission denied
```

I contacted their support, they said they can't update it. They said that i should check the Django forums for any possible solution.

Anyone had such an issue and was able to solve it? I'm hosting with Hostgator.

Comment: `/usr/lib/` is almost certainly only writable by root. And it's a pretty good bet you aren't root n any of HostGator's servers.

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting plan, so deffinetly I'm not root. I was just asking if there's a way to solve such an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Comment: Another solution would be to use virtualenv. That way all of your code would be kept in a folder inside your shared folder rather than /usr/lib. Then you'd have 100% read/write access to it without any problems.